# Set cell BackColor when column text matches

Tags: c#, gridview, radgridview, backcolor

The code below colors any cell that is equal to `Add` for the radgridview regardless of the column. How can you just set it to color when a cell in column 5 matches a text value?

```
void radGridViewFiles_CellFormatting(object sender, Telerik.WinControls.UI.CellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CellElement.Text == "Add")
    {
        e.CellElement.DrawFill = true;
        e.CellElement.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
        e.CellElement.GradientStyle = Telerik.WinControls.GradientStyles.Solid;
    }
    else
    {
        e.CellElement.ResetValue(LightVisualElement.DrawFillProperty, Telerik.WinControls.ValueResetFlags.Local);
        e.CellElement.ResetValue(VisualElement.BackColorProperty, ValueResetFlags.Local);
        e.CellElement.ResetValue(LightVisualElement.GradientStyleProperty, ValueResetFlags.Local);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Write this code in code-behind file:

```
 protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
 {
     LinkButton lnkbtn;
     if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
     {
          foreach (TableCell cell in e.Row.Cells)
          {
               lnkbtn = (LinkButton)cell.Controls[0];
               if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(GridView1.SortExpression))
               {
                   if (GridView1.SortExpression.Equals(lnkbtn.Text))
                   {
                        cell.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Crimson;
                   }
               }
          }
     }
}
```